# Viewshed with RpyGeo "rpygeo.Viewshed.sa"

Tags: r, viewshed

This function is not working:

```
rpygeo.Viewshed.sa(mnt, pt,out.raster="viewshed")

*Error in as.character.default(<S4 object of class "RasterLayer">) : 
  no method for coercing this S4 class to a vector**
```

Could someone help me on this?